# Using multiple IF statements to return a value based on multiple ranges

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to write an IF statement for whether an engine size is small (900 - 1400), medium (1401 - 2000) or large (>2000).

The engine sizes are in the B column.

I'm not really sure how to approach this. What I've currently written keeps returning an error:

```
=IF(AND(B2>=900;B2<=1400);"Small"), IF(AND(B2>=1401;B2<=2000);"Medium"), IF(B2>=2001),"Large"
```

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add the textual error that you are getting. P.S. The formula is mixing `;` and `, ` as parameter separator... you should use the one that corresponds to the regional setting of your spreadsheet i.e. use `,` for U.S.,  `;` for  Spain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ifs()`, like this:

```
=ifs( 
  not(isnumber(B2)); iferror(1/0); 
  B2 < 900; "(leptonic)"; 
  B2 <= 1400; "Small"; 
  B2 <= 2000; "Medium"; 
  true; "Large" 
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Worked a charm. I hadn't considered the IFS statement!